# MicroBatchExecution: Query terminated with error UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming, spark-streaming-kafka

Here I am trying to execute Structured Based Streaming with Apache Kafka. But in here not working and execute error (ERROR MicroBatchExecution: Query [id = daae4c34-9c8a-4c28-9e2e-88e5fcf3d614, runId = ca57d90c-d584-41d3-a8de-6f9534ead0a0] terminated with error
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z).
How can i solve this issue. I work on windows 10 machine.

**App Class:**

```
package com.rakib;

import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset;
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession;
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.OutputMode;
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQuery;
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryException;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws TimeoutException, StreamingQueryException {

        System.setProperty("hadoop.home.dir", "c:/hadoop");
        Logger.getLogger("org.apache").setLevel(Level.WARNING);

        SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
                .appName("SparkSQL")
                .master("local[*]")
                .getOrCreate();

        Dataset<Row> rowDataset = sparkSession
                .readStream()
                .format("kafka")
                .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9091,localhost:9092,localhost:9093")
                .option("subscribe", "student")
                .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
                .load();
        rowDataset.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)");


        //rowDataset.createOrReplaceTempView("student_info");
        //Dataset<Row> dataset = sparkSession.sql("SELECT value FROM student_info");


        StreamingQuery query = rowDataset
                .writeStream()
                .format("console")
                .outputMode(OutputMode.Append())
                .start();
        query.awaitTermination();


    }
}
```

**Pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Test_One</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-hdfs-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
            <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**Error:**

```
20/08/20 23:37:21 INFO MicroBatchExecution: Reading table [org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider$KafkaTable@71202043] from DataSourceV2 named 'kafka' [org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider@1a4d79db]
20/08/20 23:37:21 ERROR MicroBatchExecution: Query [id = daae4c34-9c8a-4c28-9e2e-88e5fcf3d614, runId = ca57d90c-d584-41d3-a8de-6f9534ead0a0] terminated with error
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Native Method)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access(NativeIO.java:793)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.canRead(FileUtil.java:1221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.list(FileUtil.java:1426)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.listStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:495)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.DelegateToFileSystem.listStatus(DelegateToFileSystem.java:177)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFs.listStatus(ChecksumFs.java:548)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext$Util$1.next(FileContext.java:1905)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext$Util$1.next(FileContext.java:1901)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSLinkResolver.resolve(FSLinkResolver.java:90)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext$Util.listStatus(FileContext.java:1907)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext$Util.listStatus(FileContext.java:1866)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext$Util.listStatus(FileContext.java:1825)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.FileContextBasedCheckpointFileManager.list(CheckpointFileManager.scala:299)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.HDFSMetadataLog.getLatest(HDFSMetadataLog.scala:186)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.populateStartOffsets(MicroBatchExecution.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runActivatedStream$2(MicroBatchExecution.scala:194)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:352)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken$(ProgressReporter.scala:350)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:69)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1(MicroBatchExecution.scala:191)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProcessingTimeExecutor.execute(TriggerExecutor.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.runActivatedStream(MicroBatchExecution.scala:185)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:334)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:245)
Exception in thread "stream execution thread for [id = daae4c34-9c8a-4c28-9e2e-88e5fcf3d614, runId = ca57d90c-d584-41d3-a8de-6f9534ead0a0]" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Native Method)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access(NativeIO.java:793)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.canRead(FileUtil.java:1221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.list(FileUtil.java:1426)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.listStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:495)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.DelegateToFileSystem.listStatus(DelegateToFileSystem.java:177)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFs.listStatus(ChecksumFs.java:548)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext$Util$1.next(FileContext.java:1905)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext$Util$1.next(FileContext.java:1901)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSLinkResolver.resolve(FSLinkResolver.java:90)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext$Util.listStatus(FileContext.java:1907)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext$Util.listStatus(FileContext.java:1866)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext$Util.listStatus(FileContext.java:1825)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.FileContextBasedCheckpointFileManager.list(CheckpointFileManager.scala:299)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.HDFSMetadataLog.getLatest(HDFSMetadataLog.scala:186)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.populateStartOffsets(MicroBatchExecution.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runActivatedStream$2(MicroBatchExecution.scala:194)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:352)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken$(ProgressReporter.scala:350)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:69)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1(MicroBatchExecution.scala:191)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProcessingTimeExecutor.execute(TriggerExecutor.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.runActivatedStream(MicroBatchExecution.scala:185)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:334)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:245)
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryException: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z
=== Streaming Query ===
Identifier: [id = daae4c34-9c8a-4c28-9e2e-88e5fcf3d614, runId = ca57d90c-d584-41d3-a8de-6f9534ead0a0]
Current Committed Offsets: {}
Current Available Offsets: {}

Current State: ACTIVE
Thread State: RUNNABLE

Logical Plan:
WriteToMicroBatchDataSource ConsoleWriter[numRows=20, truncate=true]
+- StreamingDataSourceV2Relation [key#7, value#8, topic#9, partition#10, offset#11L, timestamp#12, timestampType#13], org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.KafkaSourceProvider$KafkaScan@8774409, KafkaV2[Subscribe[student]]

    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:355)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution$$anon$1.run(StreamExecution.scala:245)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Native Method)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access(NativeIO.java:793)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.canRead(FileUtil.java:1221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.list(FileUtil.java:1426)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.listStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:495)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.DelegateToFileSystem.listStatus(DelegateToFileSystem.java:177)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFs.listStatus(ChecksumFs.java:548)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext$Util$1.next(FileContext.java:1905)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext$Util$1.next(FileContext.java:1901)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSLinkResolver.resolve(FSLinkResolver.java:90)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext$Util.listStatus(FileContext.java:1907)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext$Util.listStatus(FileContext.java:1866)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext$Util.listStatus(FileContext.java:1825)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.FileContextBasedCheckpointFileManager.list(CheckpointFileManager.scala:299)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.HDFSMetadataLog.getLatest(HDFSMetadataLog.scala:186)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.populateStartOffsets(MicroBatchExecution.scala:272)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runActivatedStream$2(MicroBatchExecution.scala:194)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:23)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:352)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter.reportTimeTaken$(ProgressReporter.scala:350)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.reportTimeTaken(StreamExecution.scala:69)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.$anonfun$runActivatedStream$1(MicroBatchExecution.scala:191)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProcessingTimeExecutor.execute(TriggerExecutor.scala:57)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution.runActivatedStream(MicroBatchExecution.scala:185)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.StreamExecution.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$StreamExecution$$runStream(StreamExecution.scala:334)
    ... 1 more
20/08/20 23:37:21 INFO SparkContext: Invoking stop() from shutdown hook
20/08/20 23:37:21 INFO SparkUI: Stopped Spark web UI at http://DESKTOP-3147U79:4040
20/08/20 23:37:21 INFO MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint: MapOutputTrackerMasterEndpoint stopped!
20/08/20 23:37:21 INFO MemoryStore: MemoryStore cleared
20/08/20 23:37:21 INFO BlockManager: BlockManager stopped
20/08/20 23:37:21 INFO BlockManagerMaster: BlockManagerMaster stopped
20/08/20 23:37:21 INFO OutputCommitCoordinator$OutputCommitCoordinatorEndpoint: OutputCommitCoordinator stopped!
20/08/20 23:37:21 INFO SparkContext: Successfully stopped SparkContext
20/08/20 23:37:21 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Shutdown hook called
20/08/20 23:37:21 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory C:\Users\itc\AppData\Local\Temp\temporary-850444d9-5110-4c13-881f-a6e0ba7153d8
20/08/20 23:37:21 INFO ShutdownHookManager: Deleting directory C:\Users\itc\AppData\Local\Temp\spark-813cc4f1-9d4b-44f2-99ae-435d9e99f566

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error generally occurs due to the mismatch in your binary files in your `%HADOOP_HOME%\bin` folder. So, what you need to do is to get `hadoop.dll` and `winutils.exe` specifically for your hadoop version.

Get `hadoop.dll` and `winutils.exe` for your specific hadoop version and copy them to your `%HADOOP_HOME%\bin` folder.